# MQTT delivery tokens and time out

Tags: android, eclipse, mqtt, paho

I'm developing a data critical mobile application to send messages to a server.
To get use of the lightweight nature of MQTT the KEEP_ALIVE_INTERVAL is kept at a maximum > 60 seconds. But I want to make sure that packets are delivered no matter what. Currently I use Eclipse PAHO java library.

How exactly paho handle the publishes in QoS1/2 interms of tokens? Is the timeout configurable and what is the retry policy?

I've tried the straight forward way but given my data producer produces 1 message per second, MQTT client get exhausted if the pending tokens start to stack up, I've to detect any lags and connection losses faster and, until the packets on the fly are being delivered keep the newly produced data at rest.
Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Thank you.

Comment: Were you able to find an answer to this? I'm working on a very similar Android/Mqtt messaging project. Would you be interested in collaboration?

Comment: @BaradiBaradari No I couldn't find a reasonable answer to this. And yes I'd like to discuss about this further..

Comment: Send me an email(on my profile) let's discuss

Comment: If possible, cc me too

Comment: @david so far what i know is that paho java / android client doesn't allow offline message publishing, i.e publish message even when client is not connected to the server. But for QOS>0 there is something called in-flight messages, which occurs when you try to publish messages to a disconnected server, but the disconnection is not yet registered by the client, so the messages ideally get lost, after this in flight limit exceeds an exception is thrown and you cannot publish further until the in flight messages are being delivered or failed.

Answer (score 2):

PAHO handle the publishes in QoS1/2:

## QOS 1 - one or more deliveries

### Normal Flow

- client sends a QoS 1 message (PUBLISH, SUBSCRIBE, UNSUBSCRIBE) and stores in Persistent Outbox
- client receives {PUB,SUB,UNSUB}ACK and removes message from Outbox

### Death before Acknowledgement

- client sends a QoS 1 message (PUBLISH, SUBSCRIBE, UNSUBSCRIBE) and stores in Persistent Outbox
- client dies before {PUB,SUB,UNSUB}ACK received
- client restarts with same client id and recovers Persistent Outbox
- client resends messages in Outbox
- client receives {PUB,SUB,UNSUB}ACK and removes message from Outbox

### Transfer Interrupted

- client sends a QoS 1 message (PUBLISH, SUBSCRIBE, UNSUBSCRIBE) and stores in Persistent Outbox
- broker dies before message is transferred
- client reconnects with same client id
- client resends messages in Outbox
- client receives {PUB,SUB,UNSUB}ACK and removes message from Outbox

## QOS 2 - exactly one delivery

### Normal Flow

- client sends a QoS 2 PUBLISH message and stores in Persistent Outbox
  broker replies with PUBREC
- client sends PUBREL
- broker responds with PUBCOMP
- client receives PUBCOMP and deletes message from Persistent Outbox

https://code.google.com/p/mqtt4erl/wiki/QualityOfServiceUseCases

I think you need only QoS1 for save the bandwidth and make it delivery faster